# what happens if pthread_detach is called on a thread that's already returned

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

For the following code, what is the expected behavior if the created thread "`thread_Id`" returns/finishes its work "`some_Function`" before "`pthread_detach(thread_Id)`" is called? will the resources used by "`thread_Id`" be freed?

pthread_create(&thread_Id, NULL, some_Function, &queue);
  ....

pthread_detach(thread_Id)

//no pthread_join(thread_Id,...)

Comment: difficult to read. Try to improve

Comment: If there's a risk of that, it's probably best to use a `pthread_attr_t *` instead of NULL and set the thread attributes so that the thread starets in the detached state.  See: [`pthread_attr_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_init.html) and 
[`pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.html).  I'd guess that the `pthread_detach()` would report failure and the thread state would probably not be cleaned up. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ However, the specification of [`pthread_detach()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) says: _The pthread_detach() function shall indicate to the implementation that storage for the thread thread can be reclaimed when that thread terminates. If thread has not terminated, pthread_detach() shall not cause it to terminate._ However, the rationale below says: _If an implementation detects use of a thread ID after the end of its lifetime, it is recommended that the function should fail and report an [ESRCH] error._  _[…continued 2…]_

Comment: _[…continuation 2…]_  Those rationale comments imply that if the thread terminates before it can be detached, then the resources are lost (unless you decide to `pthread_join()` the thread ID on a failure with ESRCH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `pthread_detach` on a thread whose lifetime has ended is [undefined behaviour](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html):

> If an application attempts to use a thread ID whose lifetime has ended, the        behavior is undefined."

But the [recommendation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) for the implementation of `pthread_detach` is:

> If an implementation detects use of a thread ID after the end of its lifetime, it is recommended that the function should fail and report an [ESRCH] error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the already finished thread's resources will be automatically freed.

According to Linux's `pthread_detach()` manual, it fails only for 2 reasons:

```
EINVAL - thread is not a joinable thread.
ESRCH  - No thread with the ID thread could be found.
```